# In Mysql, is there a benefit of batching multiple queries if already within a transaction?

Tags: mysql, innodb

In Mysql (innodb), is there a benefit of batching multiple queries if we are already within a database transaction?

Comment: what are your profiling results telling you?

Comment: Explain "batching".  What language are you writing in?